# Retrieve products based on attribute value

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, products, product-collection

Can anyone explain why my code gives zero results?

I am passing an attribute id from external js file to Magento. I am successfully getting the data, but the problem is, an empty page is occurring while getting the product details for corresponding attribute value.

#### My code:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

Mage::app();
$id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
echo $id;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('menu')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
        $products->addFieldToFilter(
            array(
            array('attribute'=>'menu', 'eq'=> $id)     
        )
        );
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $details[] = array('Name'=>$product->getData('name'),
        'Price' => $product->getData('price'),
        'Image' => $product->getData('image'),
        'Sku' => $product->getData('sku'),
        'Description' =>$product->getData('description'),
        'short_description' => $product->get_data('short_description'),
        'id' => $product->get_data('attribute_set_id'),
        );
        }
        print_r($details);
```

The output is an empty array.

If I directly pass the value, it gives an output:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('menu')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('price')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('image')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('description')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('short_description');
        $products->addFieldToFilter(
            array(
            array('attribute'=>'menu', 'eq'=> 243)     
        )
        );
```

Am I retrieving the `GET` parameter correctly?

Comment: did u print this collection `$products` and check if it rendered or not.?

Comment: @Manashvibirla yes i did...it is not rendering data...

Comment: print this collection after applying the filters

Comment: use trim($id)..`'eq'=> trim($id)` .May be spacing issue

Comment: @AmitBera but `$id` is not a string

Comment: try this code `(int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id')`

Comment: got output....Thanks @MeenakshiSundaramR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the id value by following code

```
$id = (int) Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
```

Comment: +Good answer +1